# SQL query not adding values from two tables after changing name of php file

Tags: php, mysql

I have written an SQL query that was working **perfectly**, it was doing everything as intended, but when I changed the name of the PHP file, for some reason, I stopped getting the right output. I have not changed a single line in the query and cannot for the life of me figure out what I've done different, besides changing the name of the PHP file.

Here is the query:

```
"SELECT ua.Username, t.Name as tariffs, ec.ElecEnergy, ua.Username as User, b.AccountBalance as UserBalance, d.Discount as DiscountUser, 
    b.VAT as UserBalance, c.ElecCharge, c.DueDate as date,
    SUM(ec.ElecEnergy) as gg,
    SUM(c.ElecCharge) as cc
FROM useraccount ua INNER JOIN
     tariff t
     ON ua.tariffs = t.id INNER JOIN
     energyconsumption ec
     ON ec.User = ua.id INNER JOIN
     balance b 
     ON b.UserBalance = ua.id INNER JOIN
     discount d 
     ON d.DiscountUser = ua.id INNER JOIN
     charge c
     ON ec.ChargeID = c.id
WHERE c.Date  = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY ua.Username, t.Name, c.DueDate";
```

I would truly appreciate if someone could help me resolve this issue!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is the current output I am getting:

```
{"results":[{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":"1900","AccountBalance":"5","Discount":"0.05","VAT":"5","ElecCharge":"266.26","DueDate":"2016-11-30"}]}
```

What I should be getting is:

```
{"results":[{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":**"3900"**,"AccountBalance":"5","Discount":"0.05","VAT":"5","ElecCharge":**"546.26**","DueDate":"2016-11-30"}]}
```

Comment: Which rdbms? Microsoft [tag:SQL-server] or [tag:mysql]?

Comment: @mendosi Hi, its mysql

Comment: Does it return the right result when you run the query from Workbench?

Comment: Since you sure the query has not been changed, then the data itself inside the database might been changed, and what you see is the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Problem has been resolved. It turns out there was an issue with my WHERE statement. I was filtering the dates that was present in the charge table when in reality I should have been filtering for the dates in the energyconsumption table.

Apologies to everyone. Silly little mistakes.